# Selenium test with PhantomJSDriver is hanging and not finishing

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

First, I start the local webapp.

Next, when I run the following test in Eclipse as a JUnit test (with `-Dbrowser=phantomjs`):

```
@Test
public void homepageShowsSearchBox() throws Exception {
    open("http://localhost:8080/app/");
    $(By.cssSelector("#someSelector")).should(exist);
}
```

The test never finishes. It's like it is hanging. (When I open the same URL in a browser the webapp is displayed)

This is the console output:

```
Feb 17, 2015 3:28:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\phantomjs
Feb 17, 2015 3:28:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 14234
Feb 17, 2015 3:28:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=14234, --webdriver-logfile=D:\Test Projects\demoapp-source\web\phantomjsdriver.log]
Feb 17, 2015 3:28:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
```

Also, there is no `phantomjsdriver.log` (the one mentioned in the log).

If useful, these are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
  <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: By the way, you can use shorter variant instead of `By.cssSelector`:

`$("#someSelector").should(exist);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, just

1) change the dependency ([reference](https://twitter.com/jselenide/status/540612294255050752)):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2) Don't use the npm-installed PhantomJS, but download the one from the website and add it as a parameter (`-Dphantomjs.binary.path="C:\bin\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe"`) ([reference](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12616))

Comment: You probably can use the npm installed PhantomJS exe. What happened was probably that Java couldn't deal with the script that actually starts the exe.

Comment: Correct, I can use the one from npm in console, but not from the JUnit test. Probably doesn't expect a .cmd but an .exe.

Comment: @MartinSpa, where is the code repository for that artifact?
com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.2.1

Comment: Hi! You can find it in Maven Central http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.codeborne%7Cphantomjsdriver%7C1.2.1%7Cjar

Comment: @MartinSpa yeah, but where is the code repository for that artifact?
Whether has it been forked from the original repository?
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/codeborne/phantomjsdriver/1.2.1/phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.pom - it states that the code base is still at https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver
But what is the actual one and what are the changes?

Comment: Honestly I haven't checked the actual changes. You can get the source from phantomjsdriver-1.2.1-sources.jar and check it out; or you can ask the author (Andrei) here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8088